# fail2ban: how to combine multiple failregex?

Tags: fail2ban

I'm having problems with adding multiple `failregex` lines in my `jail.local` file. It works if I have one line but doesn't work if I have two.

This is my my jail.local config:

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
port = 22
banaction = iptables-multiport
mode = aggressive
failregex = %(known/failregex)s
            ^Bad protocol version identification '.*' from <HOST>
failregex = %(known/failregex)s 
            ^runcloud\[\d+\]: echo: http: TLS handshake error from <ADDR>:\d+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, remove the second `failregex = %(known/failregex)s`:

failregex = %(known/failregex)s
^Bad protocol version identification '.*' from 
^runcloud[\d+]: echo: http: TLS handshake error from :\d+